# Django 1.6 class-based views: How to get the right path/to/view/ in url template tags

Tags: python, django

I have two ListView -based views inside an app called ‘events’. One is the 'events_index' that lives at /events/ and the other is a 'past_events_index' that lives at /events/past/.

Navigating directly to both urls loads the desired pages a-OK. My problem is trying to get a {% url %} template tag to link properly to the 'past_events_index'.

**apps/events/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url 
from .views import EventDetailView, EventListView, PastEventListView

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'apps.events.views',
    url(r'^$', EventListView.as_view(), name='events_index'),
    url(r'^past/$', PastEventListView.as_view(), name='past_events_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', EventDetailView.as_view(), name="events_show"),
    )
```

**apps/events/templates/events/index.html:**

```
<a href="{% url 'events:past_events_index' %}">Past Events</a>
```

Instead of pointing me to /events/past/ the above points me to /past/, which yields a 404. And this is when the user is already at /events/.

What am I missing? Is there a leading slash getting appended somewhere?

Here are my views in the interest of being complete:

**apps/events/views.py:**

```
from .models import Event
from django.views.generic import ListView
from pure_pagination.mixins import PaginationMixin
from datetime import datetime

class EventListView(ListView):
    date_today = datetime.now().date()

    queryset = Event.objects.published().filter(is_feature=False).\
        exclude(start_date__lte=date_today, end_date__isnull=True).\
        exclude(start_date__lte=date_today, end_date__lte=date_today).\
        exclude(start_date__isnull=True, end_date__lte=date_today)

    template_name = "events/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        date_today = datetime.now().date()

        context = super(EventListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['featured_event'] = Event.objects.published().filter(is_feature=True). \
            exclude(start_date__lte=date_today, end_date__isnull=True). \
            exclude(start_date__lte=date_today, end_date__lte=date_today). \
            exclude(start_date__isnull=True, end_date__lte=date_today)

        past_events = Event.objects.published().filter(is_feature=False).\
            exclude(start_date__gte=date_today).\
            exclude(start_date__isnull=True, end_date__gte=date_today)

        context['past_events'] = past_events.count()

        return context


class PastEventListView(PaginationMixin, ListView):
    date_today = datetime.now().date()

    queryset = Event.objects.published().filter(is_feature=False).\
        exclude(start_date__gte=date_today).\
        exclude(start_date__isnull=True, end_date__gte=date_today).\
        reverse()

    template_name = "events/index.html"
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PastEventListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['is_past'] = True

        return context


class EventDetailView(StatusDetailView):
    model = Event
```

**settings/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, patterns, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap

from apps.news.sitemaps import NewsSitemap


admin.autodiscover()

sitemaps = {
    'news': NewsSitemap,
    'cmspages': CMSSitemap,
}


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',

    url(r'^sitemap\.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),

    url(r'^garment/', include('apps.garment.urls')),

    # Django Admin
    (r"^%s/" % settings.ADMIN_NAMESPACE, include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r"^", include('cms.urls')),

    # Urls from apps
    url(r'^', include('apps.news.urls')),
    url(r'^events/', include('apps.events.urls', namespace='events', app_name='events')),
)

if getattr(settings, "LOCAL_SERVE", False):
    urlpatterns = patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        url(
            r"^%s(?P<path>.*)$" % settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'),
            "serve",
            {   
                'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                'show_indexes': True,
            }),
    ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns
```

Comment: namespace your event urls within your main `urls.py`, then use `'events:past_events_index'`

Comment: Just tried namespacing and my link is still pointing to /past/. I changed the template tag to {% url 'events:past_events_index' %} and I've now got this in settings/urls.py:

'code' urlpatterns = patterns(
'code'    '', 
'code'
'code' < snip >
'code'
'code'    url(r'^', include('apps.events.urls', namespace='events', app_name='events')),
'code' )


?

Comment: Pasting trouble. Try again:

Just tried namespacing and my link is still pointing to /past/. I changed the template tag to {% url 'events:past_events_index' %} and I've now got this in settings/urls.py:

[link] http://pastebin.com/dBsPSWZy

Comment: Please show the main urls.py.

Comment: settings/urls.py added above and template tag edited to use the events namespace. Same result so far.

Comment: Solved. The namespace is indeed working -- thanks @C.B. The remaining issue was that there was a 'url_prefix' field manually added to the Event model causing problems. A past dev's attempt at their own custom namespace, I guess. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with namespacing. (And then removing a custom url prefix field on the model that was overriding the namespace.) Credit to @C.B.

> namespace your event urls within your main urls.py, then use 'events:past_events_index'